# Derivation of Magnetic Energy and Ohm's Law

Tags: electromagnetism

I am currently reading section 10.1 of *Classical Electricity and Magnetism* by Panofsky and came across their derivation for magnetic energy stored in current systems.

> Consider a process in which a battery with a nonelectrostatic field E' is feeding energy both into heat losses and into a magnetic field. If we take the scalar product of j and the equation $j = \sigma(E+E')$ we obtain...

Which is Ohm's law used in the conductor. However in other introductory books on electromagnetism the derivation is done with inductance and does not mention Ohm's law, which led me to conclude that conductors do not need to satisfy the law for the magnetic energy density equation to be correct. Which of the two methods are correct; or more general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Panofsky&Phillips (P&P) derivation is limited to specific set of circumstances (battery behaving as Ohmic conductor), but the result (the formula for magnetic energy) is valid more generally. So their derivation is not the most general one, but I suspect such generality and axiomatic clarity was not their aim there. This is the usual kind of limited-validity derivation often encountered in older textbooks and shows several useful concepts at play - electromotive force $\mathbf E'$, Joule losses $j^2/\sigma$, quasi-stationary current systems. One reason to do it this way is that role (changes of) energy of electric field can be ignored, and the description is realistic (non-zero resistance).

You can take the P&P derivation and modify it by taking the limit $\sigma \to \infty$ to make it valid for a perfect conductor (perfect inductor) powered by a perfect EMF source with zero resistance. But this is the more idealized scenario (in real circuits, with changing current, there is always some non-zero resistance).

A unique EM energy formula can't be derived, it has to be *defined*, and the general definition a la Poynting is based on the Poynting theorem, derived from Maxwell's equations with no approximations.

Comment: By *defined* do you mean that there could be multiple forms of EM energy such that they satisfy Poynting's theorem? Axiomatically why would those definitions occur when we are deriving electrostatic and magnetic energy seperately? It seemed to me that the definition of "amount of work it takes to assemble charge" is well-defined.

Comment: Poynting's theorem is one possible local conservation equation, and defines one definition of EM energy. But there is infinity of expressions for EM energy density and EM energy flux density obeying a local conservation theorem. Work to assemble charge configuration is unique number only under certain restrictions, such as quasistatic motion of the charge, no radiation energy going away, no final motion of the charge. In general it depends on details of how the charge moves in the final state of motion, and also how it gets there, and thus this work cannot be used to define unique EM energy.

Comment: I might still be a bit confused... Does this mean that the EM energy flux, a.k.a. Poynting vector is also variable? For example, is it not possible to use Poynting vectors to calculate energy transferred by electromagnetic waves? This example seems like it should have a determined value.

Comment: It's not variable, it's based on a definition that is to some extent arbitrary. It is possible to calculate energy transferred in vacuum from place to place, but this number depends on definition. Energy transferred to matter is different, because that is believed to be proportional to $\mathbf E\cdot \mathbf j$ or other (in any single frame) absolute expression, and thus is not arbitrary.

Comment: I see. So to clarify; if we follow the assumptions and definition made in the Poynting theorem, it is possible to calculate the EM energy flux(also according to the definition of Poynting) with the Poynting vector? This is a bit counterintuitive as to what we usually learn in textbooks - rather than Poynting's theorem being the implication of energy conservation, it is actually defining EM energy so that the continuity equation must be satisfied.

Comment: Poynting's theorem follows from Maxwell's equations only, it does not depend on any idea of EM energy or work. It is our interpretation of this theorem as instance of local conservation of energy, which allows us to use Poynting's expressions in it, to define EM energy and EM energy flux density. Then with this definition, we can calculate EM energy in any region or flux through any surface.

Comment: There are cases where this interpretation of Poynting's theorem fails, e.g. in case of point particles, where terms in the Poynting theorem are infinite or undefined. A similar but different theorem with finite/well-defined terms can be derived from Maxwell's equations in Frenkelian EM theories where each point particle has its own "adjunct" field, and then EM energy definition can be based on that different theorem.

Comment: I think the confusion has been resolved. Thank you kindly for the explanation.

Comment: You're welcome.